# Symfony React refresh JWT automatically when cookie expires

Tags: reactjs, symfony, jwt

I'm building a Symfony React application I added the `lexik_jwt_authentication` bundle to handle JWT Authentication. I'm storing the token in an HTTP Only cookie.
I added the `gesdinet refresh token` bundle but I don't know if I should refresh it from Symfony event listener or from React with a `timeout function`.

**How could I refresh the token when the cookie expires ?**

Comment: I think it should be on React side, check if the token has expired or if will expire soon and refresh it

Comment: So I should retrieve the expiration time of my cookie to React ? Do you have any clue why it's better on react-side ?

Comment: If you use an accessToken you can read the expiration time directly from your token. "Why it's better" because how to generate a refresh token on server side if you don't have any request from your client :) (if you don't store the accesstoken in your database)

Comment: So whenever I connect I should return the accessToken expiration date, I store it on front-side and then run a setTimeout to refresh the token ? I was worried that giving the refresh token as a response was a security issue. That's why I was setting it on an HttpOnly Cookie and I wanted to handle it from server-side